# Rails gem for blog for users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, blogs

I am looking for a gem to add functionality for blogs, which can be added by either users or admin, on which users can also comment and like.

I tried blogo and monologue, but it did not work out. Is there any gem which can provide the functionality

Answer (score 4):

For any gem related detail you should search on https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/ .

This site provide you detail related what you search for. And it also provide information like Total Downloads, Releases, Current Version, Released, First Release . So you can filter better one.

[Here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=blog%20) is the detail you are looking for. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try refinerycms-blog or blogit

[RefineryCMS- Blog](https://rubygems.org/gems/refinerycms-blog)

[Blogit](https://rubygems.org/gems/blogit)